# Received Facetime Call from Someone who Didn't Call Me

Tags: iphone, facetime

My phone showed that my brother-in-law wanted to Facetime.

When I answered, all I got was the ceiling of the bathroom. He was taking a shower and hadn't called me.

Any explanation for this? There is the small possibility that he might have pressed something accidentally, but I don't think that's it.

Comment: Check you BIL for continuity or hey Siri? Singing in the shower is common. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157341/facetime-started-a-random-videocall-at-waking-mac-from-sleep

Comment: It happens... I have two people that seem to pocket FaceTime me with regularity.  Not sure what they push from which screen.  I don't even ask anymore if it's a mistake.

Comment: @bmike thanks – he doesn't have a Mac or iPad, so I don't think it's continuity. I asked him if he `Hey Siri'd`, but he says no.

Comment: If hey Siri is on, it can trigger from other noise.  Just because he isn't meaning to say "hey Siri", the device is delegated to listen and mis-interpret sounds on occasion.

Comment: I think what @bmike is suggesting is the most likely cause. I wouldn't be concerned about it unless it starts happening regularly, in which case your brother-in-law should dig deeper into what could be causing it. I've seen Hey Siri activate (albeit rarely) because the iPhone has picked up some background sound that was interpreted as "Hey Siri".